# How to create a tier price table/grid in Magento2 frontend?

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I want to table formate for tier price. please see below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change in the `app/design/frontend/yourmodule/yourtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/tier_prices.phtml`

```
<ul class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($block->hasListClass() ? $block->getListClass() : 'prices-tier items'); ?>">
    <table class="tier-price-table-shipping" width='100%'>
```

add table after `<ul>` tag,
go to line no. 105 , 
there you can add you `<tr>` and `<td>` , please check following code,

```
echo ($block->getShowDetailedPrice() !== false)
                            ? __(
        '<tr><td align="left" valigh="center" width="25%">%1</td><td align="left" valigh="center" width="25%">%2</td><td align="left" valigh="center" width="25%">Save<span class="percent tier-%3">&nbsp;%4</span>%</td><td align="left" valigh="center" width="25%">%5</td></tr>',
                                $tmp,
```

put the value as per your need.
Don't forget to close table tag before end of `</ul>` tag.

Thanks,